# Php Curl Sequential function

Tags: php, api, curl, paypal-sandbox

Is this possible? We want to achieve this sequence of functions to integrate.I'm kinda new at php curl functions. The first line of code is what we want to achieve.
Here's our php:

```
<?php
paythrougPaypalSanbox() -> publishSite() -> redirectToCurrentSite()

header("Location:".$dashboard_link);    

function paythrougPaypalSanbox() {   
    $data = $_GET['siteName'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    so on...
    curl_close($ch);
}
function publishSite() {  
    $data = $_GET['siteName'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.dudamobile.com/api/sites/multiscreen/publish/'.$siteName);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    so on..
    curl_close($ch);
}
function redirectToCurrentSite() {  
    $data = $_GET['siteName'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://trilogy.editor.multiscreensite.com/home/site/'.$siteName);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    so on..
    } 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $dashboard_link;
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Yes it is...also in the first two functions you must need to return something in order to check for `success` or `error` in the execution of every function

Comment: Hi @Hackerman thanks for the help we appreciate it. If you may, can you please help us out or give us a working example how we can process the data(consider that upon loading this php will be appending the data needed) and redirect them to actual payment.

We don't want to lose the appended data that's why, what we think after clicking a button the actual payment page will popup instead of redirecting the page, then after that the remaining functions will be fired up. :D 

Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok, first thing first, you want to execute this functions in order and when all ok, make a redirect, right?...or also you want to save some data to be displayed in the redirected page?

Comment: @Hackerman sorry for the delayed response, and btw we just want to redirect thank you! :)

Comment: I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) {
        return false;
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

if(curl($url)){
// second request
}
```